# Remove fragment from backstack issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have 4 fragments with tags Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3 and Fragment4.

I added fragments into the screen (1..4):

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
   FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(myLayoutId, fragment, tag);
   transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
   transaction.commit();
   fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

How to remove Fragment2 and Fragment3 from backstack Immediate?

**Scenario 1**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(Fragment2, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

this code removed Fragment2, Fragment3, Fragment4.

**Scenario 2**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(Fragment3, 0);
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(Fragment2, 0);
```

this code **calls onCreateView** for Fragment3 and Fragment2 (Why?!). But Fragment 4 has been removed, and Fragment2 is visible.

i.e. I want:

1. add Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3, Fragment4
2. execute method removeFragments(Fragment2, Fragment3) and this fragments should be removed. **onCreateView must NOT** be executed. After removing I need to have Fragment1 and Fragment4
3. press back button one time: Fragment4 should be removed without onCreateView for Fragment4, Fragment1 should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing: on the backstack you don't have fragments, you have **transition from one fragment to the other**. This means that the stack looks like:

```
replace Fragment3 with Fragment4
replace Fragment2 with Fragment3
replace Fragment1 with Fragment2
```

When you pop the backstack the topmost transition is reverted. What you want to achieve is having on the backstack `replace Fragment1 with Fragment4`, so when you revert it you will jump directly from Fragment4 to Fragment1. To do so you need to pop your stack until you reach Fragment1 and then insert Fragment4, for instance, when you go from 3 to 4 you could

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(Fragment2, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
transaction.replace(myLayoutId, fragment4, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

There is also a `remove` transition, but I think it works only if you added fragment instead of replacing them (not sure about that, but quite positive that it will throw exceptions when you press the back button...)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you should override the `onBackPressed`.

In `onBackPressed`, you should call this if Fragment 4 is active, otherwise call `super.onBackPressed()`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(Fragment2, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

So the question only comes down to how to know if Fragment 4 is active,

1. use `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`, I can see that you have already added tag to your fragment, you can just try to search for Fragment4, if it returns not null, then Fragment 4 is active, assuming that you only have these 4 Fragments
2. I prefer this method, simply keep a variable on which Fragment is active, which you update it in `addFragment`. Be careful, remember to save it in `onSaveInstanceState`.

**Edit:**

An alternative solution would be to call `popBackStackImmediate(Fragment2, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` immediately before add Fragment4, this may trigger unwanted animation though, you may have to try to know.

Comment: ok. I have tablet application with more than 20 various fragments. and I should to manage all fragments manually? I think, that it's no very good idea. 
findFragmentByTag always returns removed fragment, but not null. Hmmm...

Comment: and what about variable in onSaveInstance? true or false? and in onRestoeSavedInstance I should to restore my chain of the fragments manually?

Comment: From your original post, I suppose you have only one active fragment, if this is true, you only need one variable to maintain the state, and thus restore one variable.

Comment: I have left fragment with list of features, right fragment with content and content fragment can contain any fragments. ie – minimum two and maximum – five active fragments.

Comment: added an alternative way, however I still think maintaining state should be better.

Comment: yes, this is good point.  but popBackStackImmediate(Fragment1,0) or popBackStackImmediate(Fragment2, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) calls onCreateView for Fragment1. And I can't to use scenario Fragment1 -> 2 -> 3 -> (remove 2 and 3) -> fragment4 without calling onCreateView for Fragment1. onCreateView starts loading data from the server.